# iOS(Swift)で残り時間をカウントダウンするアプリを作りたい

Tags: swift

Swiftで、指定した時間までの残り時間をカウントダウンするプログラムを書いています。
しかしxcode上でも、playground上でも

```
let myComponetns = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear   | 
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour   | 
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | 
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond , 
        fromDate: myDate)
```

の部分で

> NSCalanderUnit　has no member"CalanderUnitYear"

とエラーが出ます。

また、

> myInt = myStr.toInt()!  Ambiguos reference to member "String.init"

と表示されます、

原因がわからない状態です、ご指導願えますでしょうか

```
import UIKit 

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    var cnt : Int = 0 
    var timer : NSTimer! 
    var myInt:Int = 0 

    override func viewDidLoad() { 

        let myDate: NSDate = NSDate() 
        let myCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)! 
        let myComponetns = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear   | 
            NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour   | 
            NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | 
            NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond , 
            fromDate: myDate) 

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "onUpdate:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 
        timer.fire() 

        var myStr: String = "\(myComponetns.hour)" 
        myStr += "\(myComponetns.minute)" 
        myStr += "\(myComponetns.second)" 

        myInt = myStr.toInt()! 

    } 

    func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer){ 
        cnt += 1 
        let count = myInt - cnt 
        println(count) 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーが出ないように、書き換えてみました。*開発環境は、Xcode 7.0 + Swift 2.0 + iOS 9です。先日Xcode 7が正式にリリースされました。古い環境の場合、その旨但し書きしていただいた方がいいのではないかと思います。*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cnt : Int = 0
    var timer : NSTimer!
    var myInt:Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let myDate: NSDate = NSDate()
        let myCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let myComponetns = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: NSCalendarUnit.Year.rawValue   |
            NSCalendarUnit.Hour.rawValue   |
            NSCalendarUnit.Minute.rawValue |
            NSCalendarUnit.Second.rawValue) ,
            fromDate: myDate) // 注

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "onUpdate:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()

        var myStr: String = "\(myComponetns.hour)"
        myStr += "\(myComponetns.minute)"
        myStr += "\(myComponetns.second)"

        myInt = Int(myStr)! // toInt()がSwift2より無効になったようです。

    }

    func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer){
        cnt += 1
        let count = myInt - cnt
        print(count) // println()は、Swift2よりDeprecatedになりました。
    } 

}
```

出力：

> -1
>   134515
>   134514
>   134513
>   134512
>   134511
>   134510
>   134509
>   134508
>   134507
>   134506
>   134505
>   134504（以下省略）

なんとなく、希望どおりの出力でないみたいですが、とりあえずエラーは出なくなります。

注：
`NSCalendarUnit`は、Objective-Cでは`enum`ですが、Swiftでは`struct`（構造体）です。なので、ビット演算（OR）による結合はできません。ここでは、いったん`UInt`に変換（`rawValue`）し、ビット演算（OR）で結合し、それを`init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)`で`NSCalendarUnit`に戻しています。もっとスマートな方法がありそうですが、とりあえずこう処理しました。
それと`NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear`という書き方はなく、正しくは`NSCalendarUnit.Year`です。NSCalendarのリファレンスを読み直してください。